# Does Gravitee Support Pure SOAP API integration without converting to REST

Tags: gravitee

I came across the [Gravitee API Manager](https://gravitee.io/), in their documentation they mention converting SOAP to REST and vice versa. I am working with legacy systems and I only need pure SOAP integrations. So my question is, does Gravitee support pure SOAP API integrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gravitee just as a gateway to relay SOAP calls to your backend without transformation (It is not the main purpose of Gravitee but it works fine). 
Or you can use the ["Rest to SOAP transformer"](https://docs.gravitee.io/apim_policies_rest2soap.html) policy, so the WS clients will be able to call it with REST calls which will be transformed to SOAP calls to your backend by the gateway component.